# Finding latest month and year in a table for different records

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following table

```
Name   Subject      Month  Year
-----  -----------  -----  ----
Raju   History      1      2011
Ravi   Chemistry    10     2010
Raju   Computers    12     2011
Raju   Physics      10     2010
Raju   English      6      2011 
Ravi   Mathematics  10     2010
Sunil  English      5      2011
Raju   History      5      2011 
Raju   History      6      2011
```

I want the result as follows

```
Name   Subject      Latest_Month_Attended  Latest_Year_Attended
-----  -----------  ---------------------  --------------------
Raju   History      6                      2011 
Raju   Computers    12                     2011 
Raju   Physics      10                     2010
Raju   English      6                      2011 
Ravi   Chemistry    10                     2010
Ravi   Mathematics  10                     2010 
Sunil  English      5                      2011
```

I want to find the latest month and year for the particular student and Subject

Please help me to get the above result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (edited):

```
select t1.Name, t1.Subject, max(month) as Latest_Month_Attended, t2.year as Latest_Year_Attended
from tab t1
join (
    select Name, Subject, max(year) as year
    from tab
    group by Name, Subject
) t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.subject = t2.subject and t1.year = t2.year
group by t1.Name, t1.Subject, t2.year
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is wokring fine... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH
  ranked_data AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Subject ORDER BY Year, Month) AS Rank,
    *
  FROM
    yourTable
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ranked_data
WHERE
  Rank = 1
```

However, if the Year/Month values were just combined into a single Date field - everything gets much more simple...

```
SELECT Name, Subject, MAX(Date) FROM yourTable GROUP BY Name, Subject
```

You can round dates to a month by using the following:
- `DATEADD(month, 0, DATEDIFF(month, 0, <any date-time>))`

Although there are contrary cases, my experience is normally to not break a date up, but rather keep it as a single field.

Answer (score -1):

One solution:

```
select Name, Subject, Month as Latest_Month_Attended, Year as Latest_Year_Attended
from tab
group by Name, Subject
having 
    max( month) and max(Year);
```

Result:

```
Name        Subject     Latest_Month_Attended  Latest_Year_Attended
----------  ----------  ---------------------  --------------------
Raju        Computers   12                     2011                
Raju        English     6                      2011                
Raju        History     6                      2011                
Raju        Physics     10                     2010                
Ravi        Chemistry   10                     2010                
Ravi        Mathematic  10                     2010                
Sunil       English     5                      2011
```